# Can not add items to SQL database on ReactJS backend project

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, postgresql

[image]

So I'm trying to just do a POST request to my backend where eventually a user can just add an item where it should get sent to the DB than returned. when I make a random request using Postman by putting in JSON data it keeps telling me  I'm trying to put null items in every row.

this is my code in the DB folder

```
INSERT INTO ecomerce_products
(item_id, name, price, description, img_url, quantity)
VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
RETURNING *;
```

this is my code in my controller file

```
module.exports = {
addToProducts(req, res, next) {
    const db = req.app.get("db");
    const { item_id, name, price, description, img_url, quantity } 
= req.params;
    db.addToProducts([item_id, name, price, description, img_url, 
quantity])
        .then(response => {
            res.status(200).send(response);
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
 }
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are using express or some other framework. If you are making a post request the data should be passed through the request body. Therefore `req.params` should not have those properties thus it gives null.

```
module.exports = {
addToProducts(req, res, next) {
    const db = req.app.get("db");
    console.log(req.body);
    const { item_id, name, price, description, img_url, quantity }
= req.body;

    db.addToProducts([item_id, name, price, description, img_url,
quantity])
        .then(response => {
            res.status(200).send(response);
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
 }
 };
```

Try something like this and see whether you are getting the data.

Comment: yea, I'm using express and it worked perfectly man THANKS ALOT :)